# Laravel 5.7 Email Verification Routes

Tags: php, laravel

On Laravel 5.7 Email verification feature added. But on my project i do not use the default route names and added a prefix for my own purpose. Now when i added following code to add the verify routes, it shows an error.

`Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`

Error message shows that the `verification.verify` route does not exists. Where can i update this route name in my project? Or is it the only way to use this feature is to follow the default Auth Route names?

Project Source Code Is available at https://github.com/nasirkhan/laravel-starter/tree/l57

Comment: Don't link to code that will be deleted or unpublished.

Comment: @pelmered I can see that you did not read the complete question. If you did, which you should, will see that the problem i was facing is mention clearly. And other users replied based on that. I mentioned the project link at the very end if someone needs check the full scenario.

Comment: And.. the link leads to a 404 now @nasirkhan so I guess what Pelmered mentioned happened now.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` just use `Auth::routes();` and manually add these routes:

```
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```

Then customise as you want :)

Answer (score 4):

Anyone who gets here and is looking for [tompec's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52576695/5675325) for the latest Laravel, use the below. Notice the addition of `/{hash}`.

```
$this->get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
$this->get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
$this->post('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```

Comment: Perfect Man !
I was declaring my route like this 
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
.................
Only the /{hash} was missing and after reading your answer, I was able to solve that. 
Bravo !

Comment: Instead of saying merely "latest Laravel" please specify the exact version number. It will help your post to age better.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to change the route throught which the verification process will be done you must change all the way the verification process work.

### Email verification notification process

During the registration process an event `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered` is emit. Laravel come whith a listener `Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification` which is already registered in the `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`.

After implementing the `MustVerifyEmail` interface when the `Registered` event is emit the `SendEmailVerificationNotification` listener will check if the `App\User` have already use the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` trait by checking if the user create is an instance of `MustVerifyEmail` if that is the case it will call the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` method on the `user` which get the implementation of this method when it use the `Illuminate\Auth\MustVerify`  trait.

### Customization of the verification route

To change the behavior of the verification process you can customize the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` to emit a custom `event` which can have a custom listener in which you will perform all the verification stuff and notify the `user` by email in which you will send the custom route through which the verification process will be done

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same issue and I was receiving the message

```
InvalidArgumentException 

Attribute [auth] does not exist.

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteRegistrar.php:92
```

I've solved it updating my composer executable file and laravel local files.

```
composer global self-update

composer update
```

It seems that my composer executable was using and old version of laravel installer.