# Email verify on registration, Laravel

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-7

I try to do a email verify after registration, but with my current code, my URL is changed from `"/"` tot `"/email/verify"`, but the template is not changed, I can use app with no problem . PS. I am also using VueJS. I also added `MustVerifyEmail` in `User` model, like on official [doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/verification)

PS. I receive the email registration.

**web.php**

```
Route::middleware('guest')->get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/login');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->get('/', function () {
    return view('layouts.app');
});

Route::middleware(['auth','verified'])->get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('layouts.app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**Blade file**

If I am auth I can access the app (Vuejs routes), else I will get another page like: registration, login, and verify with doesn't work.

```
    @auth
        <div id="app">
        </div>
    @else
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    @endauth
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Which URL are you referring to? If you're referring to the email verification link in the email sent to you after registration, it is one of the links that is registered through `Auth::routes(['verify' => true])`

Comment: I fix it, the problem was from my blade, I had to modify the logic. The Email Verification worked.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth:routes()` includes all the routes that is needed in authentication. When you pass `['verify' => true]` into it, it will include the email verification routes as well and that includes `email/verify`. Laravel do this for you.

You can refer to [Laravel 5.7 Email Verification Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576535/laravel-5-7-email-verification-routes)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the logic for blade, in the old one I checked if is auth / or guest, but I didn't check if its mail is verified.

```
@if(auth()->guest() || (auth()->check() && is_null(auth()->user()->email_verified_at)))

   @if(url()->current() === env('APP_URL'))
      <script>
          window.location = "/email/verify";
      </script>
   @endif

   <main class="py-4">
       @yield('content')
   </main>

@else

   <div id="app">
   </div>
   <script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>

@endif
```