# Laravel6 - Email verification customization on multi-login platform

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am new to laravel. I am trying to implement email verification on my laravel6 project.

On my project, there're three user types named 'user' 'vendor' and 'admin'. I have prepared separate directories for each user type in 'Controllers' and each of them has their own Auth files (e.g. Directory 'App/Http/Controllers/Vendor/Auth' has its own VerificationController.php, etc). So far, I've successfully implemented registration and login/logout function for each type with separate table in my DB.

A issue popped up when I tried to implement email verification. When I tried to access to a page where email verification is required, 'Auth\VerificationController@show' method seemed to be called regardless of the user type.

I went over laravel source code and learned that within the process, router calls Illuminate/Routing/Router->emailVerification() method. And the emailVerification() method routes to 'Auth\VerificationController@show' regardless of the user type.
What I wanted to do is to route depending on user type (e.g. if 'vendor' tries to login, I want to call '**Vendor**\Auth\VerificationController@show').

I don't come up with any idea how to do for that. Can anyone please give me any advice?

**Illuminate\Routing\Router class**

```
    public function emailVerification()
    {
        $this->get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
        $this->get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
        $this->post('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just put your own routes in `routes/web.php` and don't call `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`. I'd suggest using different URLs to determine user type, as you will be able to tell users apart right from the routing engine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.7 Email Verification Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576535/laravel-5-7-email-verification-routes)

Comment: Thank you. I could solve this issue by referring to Laravel 5.7 Email Verification Routes.